# SQL Server 2012 Estimated Row Numbers Much Different than Actual

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a query that cross joins two tables. `TABLE_1` has 15,000 rows and `TABLE_2` has 50,000 rows. A query very similar to this one has run in the past in roughly 10 minutes. Now it is running indefinitely with the same server situation (i.e. nothing else running), and the very similar query is also running indefinitely.

```
SELECT A.KEY_1
      ,A.FULL_TEXT_1
      ,B.FULL_TEXT_2
      ,B.KEY_2
      ,MDS_DB.MDQ.SIMILARITY(A.FULL_TEXT_1,B.FULL_TEXT_2, 2, 0, 0) AS confidence
FROM #TABLE_1 A
CROSS JOIN #TABLE_2 B
WHERE MDS_DB.MDQ.SIMILARITY(A.FULL_TEXT_1,B.FULL_TEXT_2, 2, 0, 0) >= 0.9
```

When I run the estimated execution plan for this query, the `Nested Loops (Inner Join)` node is estimated at 96% of the execution. The estimated number of rows is 218 million, even though cross joining the tables should result in 15,000 * 50,000 = 750 million rows. When I add `INSERT INTO #temp_table` to the beginning of the query, the estimated execution plan puts `Insert Into` at 97% and estimates the number of rows as 218 million. In reality, there should be less than 100 matches that have a similarity score above 0.9.

I have read that large differences in estimated vs. actual row counts can impact performance. What could I do to test/fix this?

Comment: You could probably see some performance increase by not using your scalar function in the column list and the WHERE clause. This blog post is pretty helpful in explaining the best practice here. https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3845381/T-SQL-Best-Practices-150-Don146t-Use-Scalar-Value-Functions-in-Column-List-or-WHERE-Clauses.htm

Comment: 750 million rows from temp tables? Do you really need that much data in tempdb?

Comment: estimated execution plan != actual execution plan. But to answer your question, see when the last time the statistics were updated. That's where the rowcount comes from for the optimizer which uses it to determine memory and cpu requirements. Maybe they need updating (maybe you don't have auto-update stats turned on)

Comment: @Sean the 750 million comes from the cross join, so I don't think it's actually in tempdb, but I could be wrong. the 15K table is varchar items of one type created in the last week, the 50K table is all varchar items of a second type.

Comment: @scsimon understood on the difference between estimated and actual. I don't think updating statistics would do much good since it is working entirely off two small temp temp tables. I could be wrong though!

Comment: I hope when you say text you mean character data, not the actual text datatype.

Comment: yes, they are varchar type (updated my comment) - under 300 characters

Comment: [Statistics matter on temp tables too](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/statistics-matter-on-temp-tables-too/). Naturally you didn't show us all the work before that single query.

Comment: @scsimon fair enough. However, in this case the estimated execution plan is correctly gathering the row counts for each temp table. they are dropped/created each time before this query is run which (I think) mitigates some of the challenges discussed in the article you linked.

Comment: @digital.aaron interesting article - thank you. However, I'm not sure it applies to a function with a cross join. that similarity needs to be calculated for every single row, so I would expect separate calls for each row.

Comment: @CameronTaylor did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @juvian I did - thank you! It did not noticeably speed up performance, although I am including it by default moving forward.

Comment: @CameronTaylor thats weird, are all texts of similar length?  and does changing the hint to 0.99 make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that large differences in estimated vs. actual row counts can impact performance. What could I do to test/fix this?

Yes, this is true.  It particularly affects optimizations involving join algorithms, aggregation algorithms, and indexes.

But it is not true for your query.  Your query has to do a nested loops join with no indexes.  All pairs of values in the two tables need to be compared.  There is little algorithmic flexibility and (standard) indexes cannot really help.

Comment: Thank you - so there's not much I can do? It's just concerning because an earlier query last week ran quicker for less rows. I'm guessing there's some other factor/environment change causing the slowdown...I just can't put my finger on what.

Comment: I don't think so.  It has to process every pair of rows in the two tables, which according to your calculations is 750 million rows.  There isn't a short-cut.

Answer (score 1):

For better performance, use the [minScoreHint parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ee633878(v=sql.105)). This allows to prevent doing the full similarity calculation for many pairs and early exit.

So this should run quicker:

```
SELECT A.KEY_1
      ,A.FULL_TEXT_1
      ,B.FULL_TEXT_2
      ,B.KEY_2
      ,MDS_DB.MDQ.SIMILARITY(A.FULL_TEXT_1,B.FULL_TEXT_2, 2, 0, 0, 0.9) AS confidence
FROM #TABLE_1 A
CROSS JOIN #TABLE_2 B
WHERE MDS_DB.MDQ.SIMILARITY(A.FULL_TEXT_1,B.FULL_TEXT_2, 2, 0, 0, 0.9) >= 0.9
```

It is not clear from docs if 0.9 results would be included. If not, change 0.9 to 0.89

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by scsimon will help you prove whether it's statistics or not. Have the estimates changed significantly since to when it was running fast?

Parallelism spring to mind. If the query was going parallel, but now isn't (e.g. if a server setting has been changed, or statistics) then that could cause significant performance degradation.

Comment: I appreciate it - definitely a helpful link. However, the temp table statistics are being estimated correctly, and there is only one step in creating them. no server settings have changed. unfortunately I didn't capture estimates in the previous iteration since I didn't realize it was going to be a problem.